# Stuck with ListViews and Adapters

Tags: java, android, android-layout, listview, checkbox

Well, im trying to do a screen which takes a few fields and then, it sends the information to my server. The code works and I can make the insertion, but now, i´m trying to complete the screen with a checkbox selector for the class groups of my app.

The problem, is than i have a variable number of groups in the different courses so i have to do it dynamic.

The class in which I work is this. The wrapped code between opinions is where failure

```
 public class NuevaTarea extends Activity {

    EditText nombretarea;
    DatePicker fechainicio, fechafin;
    ExpandableListView listagrupos;
    Button crear;
    TimePicker horainicio, horafin;
    ProgressDialog pDialog;
    Httppostaux post;
    CheckBox op1, op2, op3, op4, op5;
    JSONArray Grupos;
    ArrayList<PostData> data;
    PostAdapter adapter;
    ListView lista;






    @SuppressWarnings("null")
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {  {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_insertatarea);


        nombretarea = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        fechainicio = (DatePicker) findViewById(R.id.datePicker1);
        fechafin = (DatePicker) findViewById(R.id.datePicker2);
        listagrupos = (ExpandableListView) findViewById(R.id.expandableListView1);
        crear = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttoncrear);
        horainicio = (TimePicker) findViewById(R.id.timePicker1);
        horafin = (TimePicker) findViewById(R.id.timePicker2);
        op1 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);
        op2 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBox2);
        op3 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBox3);
        op4 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBox4);
        op5 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBox5);

        //////////////// Grupos


        Log.d("Grupos", "Previo Inicio");
        if ( savedInstanceState == null) {
            Log.d("Grupos", "SavedInstance == NULL");
            Log.d("Todos los Grupos", "ARRAY GRUPOS = " + Constantes.cargainfogrupos);
            //new asynccargagrupos().execute();
            Log.d("Todos los Grupos", "ARRAY GRUPOS = " + Constantes.cargainfogrupos);
            data = new ArrayList<PostData>();
            if ( Constantes.cargainfogrupos != null) {
                Log.d("Grupos", "Grupos != NULL");
                Log.d("Grupos", "Dentro del WHILE");
                    String tex;
                    try {
                        Log.d("Grupos", "Dentro del Try");
                        for ( int i = 0; i < Constantes.cargainfogrupos.length(); i++){
                            Log.d("Grupos", "Dentro del For");
                            JSONObject jsonObject = Constantes.cargainfogrupos.getJSONObject(i);
                            tex = jsonObject.getString("nombregrupo");
                            data.add(new PostData(tex, false));
                            Log.d("Grupos", "Primera Vista a data" + data);
                        }
                        Log.d("Grupos", "Version de Data que paso a Adapter" + data);
                        adapter = new PostAdapter(NuevaTarea.this, data);

                    }
                    catch (Exception e){

                    }

            }

        }else {
            Log.d("Grupos", "ELSE");
            data = savedInstanceState.getParcelableArrayList("saveddata");
            adapter = new PostAdapter(NuevaTarea.this, data);       
        }
        ListView lv = (ListView) findViewById(android.R.id.list);
        lv.setAdapter(adapter);

        /////////////////// GRUPOS
```

My XML file is

```
 <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Nombre Tarea" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10" >
    </EditText>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Tipo de Tarea" />

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/checkBox1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Examen Práctico Parcial" />

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/checkBox2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Examen Práctico Final" />

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/checkBox3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Examen Teórico Parcial" />

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/checkBox4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Exament Teórico Final" />

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/checkBox5"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Entregable" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Fecha de Inicio" />

    <TimePicker
        android:id="@+id/timePicker1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />


    <DatePicker
        android:id="@+id/datePicker1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/FechaFinalizacion"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="TextView" />

    <TimePicker
        android:id="@+id/timePicker2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />


   <DatePicker
        android:id="@+id/datePicker2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
   <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Grupo" />

    <ExpandableListView
        android:id="@+id/expandableListView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
    </ExpandableListView>

    <!--  CHECKBOXs --> 

    <RelativeLayout 
    android:id="@+id/LinearLayout1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#999999"
    android:padding="2dp" >

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/leido"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:focusable="false" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvTitulo"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/leido"
        android:text="Titulo del post"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

     <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
    </ListView>



    </RelativeLayout>



    <!--  CHECKBOXs --> 
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttoncrear"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Crea Tarea" />



        </LinearLayout>


    </ScrollView>



</LinearLayout>
```

And i used two external class, PostData and PostAdapter

```
public class PostData implements Parcelable{

  private String titulo;
  private boolean leido;

  public PostData(String equip, boolean checked) {

      this.titulo = equip;
      this.leido = checked;

   }

   public PostData(Parcel in){
       this.titulo= in.readString();
       this.leido = in.readInt() == 1 ? true:false;
    }


   public void setChecked(boolean value) {
     this.leido = value;
 }

   public boolean getChecked() {
       return leido;
   }

   public String getEquipos() {
        return titulo;
  }

   public void setEquipos(String equipos) {
        this.titulo = equipos;
  }

   @Override
   public int describeContents() {
     return 0;
   }

   @Override
   public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
     dest.writeString(getEquipos());
     dest.writeInt(getChecked() ? 1 : 0);
    }

   public static final Parcelable.Creator<PostData> CREATOR = new Parcelable.Creator<PostData>() {
     public PostData createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
           return new PostData(in);
        }

       public PostData[] newArray(int size) {
          return new PostData[size];
      }
   };
```

And this is my class PostAdapter

```
public class PostAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

static class ViewHolder
 {
      TextView tvFecha_pub;
      TextView tvtitulo_post;
      CheckBox cb;
    }

   private static final String TAG = "CustomAdapter";
  private static int convertViewCounter = 0;

  private ArrayList<PostData> data;
   private LayoutInflater inflater = null;

 public PostAdapter(Context c, ArrayList<PostData> d)
    {
       Log.v(TAG, "Constructing CustomAdapter");

       this.data = d;
      inflater = LayoutInflater.from(c);
  }

   @Override
   public int getCount()
   {
       Log.v(TAG, "in getCount()");
        return data.size();
 }

   @Override
   public Object getItem(int position)
 {
       Log.v(TAG, "in getItem() for position " + position);
        return data.get(position);
  }

   @Override
   public long getItemId(int position)
 {
       Log.v(TAG, "in getItemId() for position " + position);
      return position;
    }

   @Override
   public int getViewTypeCount()
   {
       Log.v(TAG, "in getViewTypeCount()");
        return 1;
   }

   @Override
   public int getItemViewType(int position)
    {
       Log.v(TAG, "in getItemViewType() for position " + position);
        return 0;
   }

   @Override
   public void notifyDataSetChanged()
  {
       super.notifyDataSetChanged();
   }

   @Override
   public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
   {

       ViewHolder holder;

      Log.v(TAG, "in getView for position " + position + ", convertView is "
              + ((convertView == null) ? "null" : "being recycled"));

     if (convertView == null)
        {
           convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_insertatarea, null);

          convertViewCounter++;
            Log.v(TAG, convertViewCounter + " convertViews have been created");

            holder = new ViewHolder();


            holder.tvtitulo_post = (TextView) convertView
                   .findViewById(R.id.tvTitulo);
            holder.cb = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.leido);
            holder.cb.setOnClickListener(checkListener);

            convertView.setTag(holder);

     } else
          holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();

     // Para porde hacer click en el checkbox
        PostData d = (PostData) getItem(position);
      holder.cb.setTag(d);
        // Setting all values in listview

      holder.tvtitulo_post.setText(data.get(position).getEquipos());
      holder.cb.setChecked(data.get(position).getChecked());

      return convertView;
 }

   public void setCheck(int position)
  {
       PostData d = data.get(position);

        d.setChecked(!d.getChecked());
      notifyDataSetChanged();
 }

   public void checkAll(boolean state)
 {
       for (int i = 0; i < data.size(); i++)
           data.get(i).setChecked(state);
  }

   public void cancelSelectedPost()
    {

       int i = 0;
      while (i < getCount())
      {
           if (data.get(i).getChecked())
           {
               data.remove(data.indexOf(data.get(i)));
         } else
              i++;
        }
       notifyDataSetChanged();

 }

   public boolean haveSomethingSelected()
  {
       for (int i = 0; i < data.size(); i++)
           if (data.get(i).getChecked())
               return true;
        return false;
   }

   /**
  * Este método es para poder seleccionar una fila directamente con el
    * checkbox en lugar de tener que pulsar en la liste en sí
   */
 private OnClickListener checkListener = new OnClickListener()
   {

       @Override
       public void onClick(View v)
     {
           PostData d = (PostData) v.getTag();
         d.setChecked(!d.getChecked());
      }
   };

}
```

And I'm stuck with this error log

```
 07-14 20:34:52.972: E/AndroidRuntime(5961): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    07-14 20:34:52.972: E/AndroidRuntime(5961): java.lang.ClassCastException:    android.widget.LinearLayout cannot be cast to android.widget.CalendarView$WeekView
07-14 20:34:52.972: E/AndroidRuntime(5961):     at android.widget.CalendarView.onScroll(CalendarView.java:1183)
07-14 20:34:52.972: E/AndroidRuntime(5961):     at android.widget.CalendarView.access$900(CalendarView.java:76)
07-14 20:34:52.972: E/AndroidRuntime(5961):     at android.widget.CalendarView$2.onScroll(CalendarView.java:1075)
07-14 20:34:52.972: E/AndroidRuntime(5961):     at android.widget.AbsListView.invokeOnItemScrollListener(AbsListView.java:1340)
07-14 20:34:52.972: E/AndroidRuntime(5961):     at android.widget.ListView.layoutChildren(ListView.java:1762)
07-14 20:34:52.972: E/AndroidRuntime(5961):     at android.widget.AbsListView.onLayout(AbsListView.java:2012)
07-14 20:34:52.972: E/AndroidRuntime(5961):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14289)
07-14 20:34:52.972: E/AndroidRuntime(5961):     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4562)
07-14 20:34:52.972: E/AndroidRuntime(5961):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1671)
07-14 20:34:52.972: E/AndroidRuntime(5961):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1525)
07-14 20:34:52.972: E/AndroidRuntime(5961):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1434)
07-14 20:34:52.972: E/AndroidRuntime(5961):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14289)
07-14 20:34:52.972: E/AndroidRuntime(5961):     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4562)
07-14 20:34:52.972: E/AndroidRuntime(5961):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:448)
07-14 20:34:52.972: E/AndroidRuntime(5961):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14289)
07-14 20:34:52.972: E/AndroidRuntime(5961):     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4562)
07-14 20:34:52.972: E/AndroidRuntime(5961):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1671)
07-14 20:34:52.972: E/AndroidRuntime(5961):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutHorizontal(LinearLayout.java:1660)
07-14 20:34:52.972: E/AndroidRuntime(5961):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1436)
07-14 20:34:52.972: E/AndroidRuntime(5961):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14289)
07-14 20:34:52.972: E/AndroidRuntime(5961):     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4562)
07-14 20:34:52.972: E/AndroidRuntime(5961):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:448)
07-14 20:34:52.972: E/AndroidRuntime(5961):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14289)
07-14 20:34:52.972: E/AndroidRuntime(5961):     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4562)
07-14 20:34:52.972: E/AndroidRuntime(5961):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1671)
07-14 20:34:52.972: E/AndroidRuntime(5961):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1525)
07-14 20:34:52.972: E/AndroidRuntime(5961):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1434)
07-14 20:34:52.972: E/AndroidRuntime(5961):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14289)
07-14 20:34:52.972: E/AndroidRuntime(5961):     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4562)
07-14 20:34:52.972: E/AndroidRuntime(5961):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:448)
07-14 20:34:52.972: E/AndroidRuntime(5961):     at android.widget.ScrollView.onLayout(ScrollView.java:1459)
07-14 20:34:52.972: E/AndroidRuntime(5961):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14289)
07-14 20:34:52.972: E/AndroidRuntime(5961):     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4562)
07-14 20:34:52.972: E/AndroidRuntime(5961):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1671)
07-14 20:34:52.972: E/AndroidRuntime(5961):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1525)
07-14 20:34:52.972: E/AndroidRuntime(5961):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1434)
07-14 20:34:52.972: E/AndroidRuntime(5961):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14289)
07-14 20:34:52.972: E/AndroidRuntime(5961):     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4562)
07-14 20:34:52.972: E/AndroidRuntime(5961):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:448)
07-14 20:34:52.972: E/AndroidRuntime(5961):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14289)
07-14 20:34:52.972: E/AndroidRuntime(5961):     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4562)
07-14 20:34:52.972: E/AndroidRuntime(5961):     at com.android.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onLayout(ActionBarOverlayLayout.java:349)
07-14 20:34:52.972: E/AndroidRuntime(5961):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14289)
07-14 20:34:52.972: E/AndroidRuntime(5961):     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4562)
07-14 20:34:52.972: E/AndroidRuntime(5961):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:448)
07-14 20:34:52.972: E/AndroidRuntime(5961):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14289)
07-14 20:34:52.972: E/AndroidRuntime(5961):     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4562)
07-14 20:34:52.972: E/AndroidRuntime(5961):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:1976)
07-14 20:34:52.972: E/AndroidRuntime(5961):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1730)
07-14 20:34:52.972: E/AndroidRuntime(5961):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1004)
07-14 20:34:52.972: E/AndroidRuntime(5961):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5481)
07-14 20:34:52.972: E/AndroidRuntime(5961):     at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:749)
07-14 20:34:52.972: E/AndroidRuntime(5961):     at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:562)
07-14 20:34:52.972: E/AndroidRuntime(5961):     at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:532)
07-14 20:34:52.972: E/AndroidRuntime(5961):     at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:735)
07-14 20:34:52.972: E/AndroidRuntime(5961):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)
07-14 20:34:52.972: E/AndroidRuntime(5961):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
07-14 20:34:52.972: E/AndroidRuntime(5961):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
07-14 20:34:52.972: E/AndroidRuntime(5961):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
07-14 20:34:52.972: E/AndroidRuntime(5961):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-14 20:34:52.972: E/AndroidRuntime(5961):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
07-14 20:34:52.972: E/AndroidRuntime(5961):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
07-14 20:34:52.972: E/AndroidRuntime(5961):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
07-14 20:34:52.972: E/AndroidRuntime(5961):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-14 20:39:55.014: E/AndroidRuntime(5993): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-14 20:39:55.014: E/AndroidRuntime(5993): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.PFC.pablo/com.PFC.pablo.Cursos}: java.lang.NullPointerException
07-14 20:39:55.014: E/AndroidRuntime(5993):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2211)
07-14 20:39:55.014: E/AndroidRuntime(5993):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2261)
07-14 20:39:55.014: E/AndroidRuntime(5993):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
07-14 20:39:55.014: E/AndroidRuntime(5993):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1256)
07-14 20:39:55.014: E/AndroidRuntime(5993):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
07-14 20:39:55.014: E/AndroidRuntime(5993):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
07-14 20:39:55.014: E/AndroidRuntime(5993):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
07-14 20:39:55.014: E/AndroidRuntime(5993):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-14 20:39:55.014: E/AndroidRuntime(5993):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
07-14 20:39:55.014: E/AndroidRuntime(5993):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
07-14 20:39:55.014: E/AndroidRuntime(5993):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
07-14 20:39:55.014: E/AndroidRuntime(5993):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-14 20:39:55.014: E/AndroidRuntime(5993): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
07-14 20:39:55.014: E/AndroidRuntime(5993):     at com.PFC.pablo.Cursos.agregarFilasTabla(Cursos.java:113)
07-14 20:39:55.014: E/AndroidRuntime(5993):     at com.PFC.pablo.Cursos.onCreate(Cursos.java:74)
07-14 20:39:55.014: E/AndroidRuntime(5993):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5133)
07-14 20:39:55.014: E/AndroidRuntime(5993):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
07-14 20:39:55.014: E/AndroidRuntime(5993):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2175)
07-14 20:39:55.014: E/AndroidRuntime(5993):     ... 11 more
```

When I try to load the Activity, everything works, and even get to do well NuevaTarea.java for loop getting the data well, but that's where broken. Specifically, came up here and from there it does not pass

```
    Log.d("Grupos", "Version de Data que paso a Adapter" + data);
                    adapter = new PostAdapter(NuevaTarea.this, data);
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

From the stack trace it seems that your are casting a LinearLayout to a CalendarView somewhere is a class called Cursos.

You probably have a line something like

```
LinearLayout mLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.my_view);
```

But the view that has the id R.id.my_view is actually a calendar view.

Comment: The thing is that I have no CalendarView in this activity and I am using the class courses here, so I'm going crazy.

Comment: From Cursos? No, I get the error from Cursos when the app try to "back" to that Activity with a field that I don't have initialization correctly.

If I comment the code between the lines //////Grupos, it works perfectly and I can insert the information, except the field that I have to get from the CheckBoxes that I'm trying to create

Comment: Well, something I've made ​​progress. 
In my class NuevaTarea when I have an error in this line

    ListView lv = (ListView) findViewById(android.R.id.list);

It´s R.id.listView1. And I can run the Activity, but it doesn´t work correctly. I have problems with XML as I have duplicates, and I fail to create all Checkbox, but at least it takes the values ​​from JSONArray to create the first.

Comment: Hmmm interesting...it must be just one little line of code that is screwing everything up. I'm not sure what it is though...

Comment: At least it works, the problem now is that after printing the TextView I call groups, doubling me again ALL Activity screen, so I have all four of Checkbox instead of four.